# Funny behaviour from Adobe Flex Transitions-Possible Bug

Tags: apache-flex, mxml, flex4.5, transition

I think I've just spotted an apparent **bug** in **flex 4.5**.

The link to the relevant application is **[here](http://queirozf.com/lessonslearnt/lessonslearnt.html)**. **VIEW SOURCE ENABLED!!**

These are the transitions:

```
<s:states>
    <s:State name="State1"/>
    <s:State name="State2"/>
    <s:State name="State3"/>
</s:states>

<s:transitions>

    <s:Transition fromState="State1" toState="State2" autoReverse="true" >
        <s:Sequence>
            <s:Move duration="500" target="{goButton}"/>
            <s:AddAction targets="{[tagsLabel,tagsTextInput]}"/>
            <s:Fade targets="{[tagsLabel,tagsTextInput]}" duration="500" />
        </s:Sequence>
    </s:Transition>

    <s:Transition fromState="State1" toState="State3" >
        <s:Sequence>
            <s:RemoveAction targets="{[searchLabel,searchTextInput,inLabel,inDropDownList]}" />
            <s:Move duration="500" target="{goButton}" />
            <s:AddAction target="{lessonsDataGrid}" />
        </s:Sequence>
    </s:Transition>


    <s:Transition fromState="State2" toState="State3" >
        <s:Sequence>
            <s:RemoveAction targets="{[searchLabel,searchTextInput,inLabel,inDropDownList,tagsLabel,tagsTextInput]}" />
            <s:Move duration="500" target="{goButton}" />
            <s:AddAction target="{lessonsDataGrid}" />
        </s:Sequence>
    </s:Transition>

    <s:Transition fromState="State3" toState="State1" >
        <s:Sequence>
            <s:RemoveAction target="{lessonsDataGrid}" />
            <s:Move target="{goButton}" duration="500" />
            <s:AddAction targets="{[searchLabel,searchTextInput,inLabel,inDropDownList]}" />
        </s:Sequence>
    </s:Transition>

</s:transitions>
```

You see I'm working a little bit with Transitions here; one transition gets activated on the `DropDownList` `indexChangeEvent` and another is triggered by the `clickEvent` on the magnifier `Button`.

The problem I'm facing is as follows:

If I click the 'magnifier' `Button` **three times**,(not 3 times in quick succession, but 1 click, wait for the transition, another click, wait for the transition, last click) then I get some **funny behaviour**: the magnifier `Button` vanishes, even though I've never made it disappear in the transitions; and the `TextInput` which was supposed to disappear didn't; it somehow got **stuck** in `State3` which is the state with the `Datagrid` in it.

Trust me, I've spent at least **4 hours** on this writing and rewriting those transitions, I tried all sorts of things on the web but to no avail.

Hope someone can help, I'd hate to have to accept that Flex has got a bug. I'd be relieved to know it was something I did wrong and that Flex is still reliable.

Many thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've played around with it for a while. Noticed that by some reason when changing the states, one of the AddItems overrides removes the element with index 0 from the Border container (you can debug and see for yourself  if you add a handler for the removedFromStage event to the goButton). I'm still investigating the problem but i have a quick fix for you. Just include the goButton in all three states:  includeIn="State1,State2,State3" and it won't disappear :]
If I find the reason i'll post it to you.

Hope that helps,

*Blaze*